# Mobile Browser Fixed elements moving with tool bar shrink

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-position

I'm working on a site which has a background SVG with fixed position in the centre of the page. This works fine on desktop but on mobile it moves as the browser search bar and footer shrink on scroll. I'm looking for a way to combat this movement and keep the image perfectly in the centre without moving.

current css

```
 .background-name svg{
            height: 8vw;
            position: sticky;
            top: 50vh;
        } 

.background-name svg {
  margin-left: 1px;
  height: 56px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none;
```

html

```
<div class="background-name">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 145.14 42.77"><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path d="M24.31,3.27A11.31,11.31,0,0,1,28,12.21a11.37,11.37,0,0,1-3.71,9q-3.72,3.3-10.62,3.3H3.83V42H0V0H13.69Q20.59,0,24.31,3.27ZM3.83,21h9.8c3.38,0,6-.76,7.73-2.3A8.11,8.11,0,0,0,24,12.21a8.06,8.06,0,0,0-2.65-6.43q-2.66-2.3-7.73-2.3H3.83Z"/><path d="M49.71,14.16c2,1.93,3,4.8,3,8.61V34.63A36.27,36.27,0,0,0,53.34,42H49.91a23.08,23.08,0,0,1-.41-4.55h-.12Q46.32,42.61,38.7,42.6a10.84,10.84,0,0,1-7.34-2.42,7.81,7.81,0,0,1-2.8-6.2,7.46,7.46,0,0,1,2.56-6q2.56-2.19,8.82-3.19c2.87-.47,5.94-.83,9.21-1.06V22.3q0-4-2.07-6a7.82,7.82,0,0,0-5.6-1.94,8.21,8.21,0,0,0-5.67,1.8,6.79,6.79,0,0,0-2.18,4.86H29.79A10,10,0,0,1,33.13,14c2-1.81,4.81-2.71,8.35-2.71S47.72,12.23,49.71,14.16ZM40.42,27.85c-3,.43-5,1.1-6.2,2a4.63,4.63,0,0,0-1.77,3.9A5.24,5.24,0,0,0,34.31,38a7.79,7.79,0,0,0,5.16,1.56,10.93,10.93,0,0,0,3.87-.68,8.08,8.08,0,0,0,3-2,9.64,9.64,0,0,0,2.19-3.28,13.78,13.78,0,0,0,.59-4.51v-2.3C46.59,27,43.68,27.34,40.42,27.85Z"/><path d="M74.28,12v3.48a15,15,0,0,0-1.89-.12,8.56,8.56,0,0,0-6.9,2.83c-1.61,1.89-2.42,4.56-2.42,8V42H59.41V12H63v4.72h.12A9.89,9.89,0,0,1,67,13.07a11,11,0,0,1,5.31-1.27A10.14,10.14,0,0,1,74.28,12Z"/><path d="M95.81,42,80.89,26.55h-.12V42H77.11V0h3.66V24.6h.12L94.22,12h5L84.66,25.49,100.89,42Z"/><path d="M118.53,37.85a8.31,8.31,0,0,0,3-4.75h3.77a11.55,11.55,0,0,1-4,6.9,12.9,12.9,0,0,1-8.64,2.77,12.35,12.35,0,0,1-10-4.39Q98.94,34,98.94,26.49a18.37,18.37,0,0,1,1.62-7.88,12.66,12.66,0,0,1,4.66-5.39,13,13,0,0,1,7.17-2,12.42,12.42,0,0,1,8.35,2.83A13.36,13.36,0,0,1,125.08,22a28.16,28.16,0,0,1,.47,5.78H102.66c.08,3.85,1,6.81,2.89,8.85a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,7.08,3.07A9.28,9.28,0,0,0,118.53,37.85ZM105.61,17.17a11.27,11.27,0,0,0-2.89,7.55H122a11.66,11.66,0,0,0-2.89-7.61,9.7,9.7,0,0,0-13.51.06Z"/><path d="M145.14,12v3.48a15,15,0,0,0-1.89-.12,8.56,8.56,0,0,0-6.9,2.83c-1.62,1.89-2.42,4.56-2.42,8V42h-3.66V12h3.6v4.72H134a9.89,9.89,0,0,1,3.83-3.69,11,11,0,0,1,5.31-1.27A10.14,10.14,0,0,1,145.14,12Z"/></g></g></svg></div>
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Cheers, 
Tim

Comment: please add the html codes.

Comment: Why do you use this magic and no classic backround with background position?

Comment: @DogukanCavus Added now.

Comment: @MegoSoft - that didnt work either unfortunately

Comment: I don't understand what the problem. why you using the `position:sticky`? use `position:fixed`

Comment: @DogukanCavus the fixed image is moving when when the toolbar moves as a result of scrolling in mobile - as though the top property is based on the toolbar rather than the top of the window. have tried position fixed aswell